# Do "body only" DSLR cameras come with a battery?

Tags: dslr, battery

I am a novice on photography and planning to gift a DSLR camera to someone - 
Do the cameras - that claim body only products - have battery included with them?.

Can anyone confirm if below product on amazon includes the battery and charger?.

[http://www.amazon.com/Canon-T3i-Digital-Imaging-18-55mm/dp/tech-data/B004J3V90Y/ref=de_a_smtd](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004J3V90Y)

Thanks,
Anna

Comment: The vendor should provide a list of exactly what is included in the box; if it's not on the list, you don't get it. :) While answers will give standard practice, that's always changing as vendors are continually trying to cut costs. I'd suggest reading the fine print regarding the specific body you want to buy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of the camera bodies being produced by major manufacturers (Canon, Nikon, Sony, Pentax, Olympus, etc) ship with a battery and charger.  You don't need to purchase an additional battery or charger.

Comment: Almost. The Pentax K-x does not ship with a charger and the included batteries are disposable Lithium.

Comment: FWIW the older Pentax cameras came with frustrating alkaline AA batteries that would only last for 20 shots. The disposable lithium batteries should last for 1500 or so.

Comment: "Included charger" doesn't always mean "included USEFUL charger" either - eg some Sony cameras come with a basic USB plugpack to power the sloooow in camera charger, but not a dedicated charger....

Answer (score 11):

Yes, they do. "Body only" means as opposed  to in a kit with a lens. You should actually get a battery, matching charger (except in the now-rare case of cameras which use AA cells), an instruction manual and probably a CD with software, maybe some random cables, and various other little bits and pieces like a viewfinder cover.  In fact, the manual will probably have a page listing what all is included.

The link you've given isn't "body only". It looks like the standard "kit", which includes all that *plus* a basic entry-level zoom lens. The "non-kit" version sold as "body only" *still* will have all of the basics listed above, though.

The main vital bit that you'll need to buy immediately is a memory card — these are pretty much never included.

Beware, though, of unscrupulous too-good-to-be-true online vendors. One favorite trick is to open the box and take all that stuff out, and then sell it separately at outrageous markup. Or sell cheaper third-party replacements at even more outrageous markup. No reputable licensed dealer will do that. If someone starts to imply that this is the way it is, cancel the transaction and buy from somewhere else.

Comment: Except Pentax K-x, see comment to @ahockley's answer.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. But even those Pentax ships with batteries, yeah?

Answer (score 4):

A 'body only' kit includes everything you need to start shooting except for a lens and a memory card. However it is always worth buying a spare battery (use the camera's brand, not a cheap 'compatible' model) and keep it charged up so if you're caught short with the camera's installed battery you can continue shooting with the spare. It also means that when one battery is charging you can still use the camera rather than wait for the charge to complete (can take an hour or so of missed opportunities otherwise!).

Answer (score 2):

Usually, they do. However, sometimes cheaper models use standard AA batteries and in such case, a charger or even batteries are not included.

From current lineup, the only such model I know is Pentax K-x, which comes with non-rechargeable batteries and no charger.